# Do all objects sit in the same address space in C?

Tags: c

I am trying to work out if the C standard require that all addresses are in the same address space. If I have two objects of different type

```
double d;
int i;
```

I cannot do pointer arithmetic on their addresses, because they are pointers of different types. However, the standard says that I can point character type pointers there and will get the address of the first byte in the objects.

```
char *dp = (char *)&d;
char *ip = (char *)&i;
```

and with those I can do pointer arithmetic, and for example figure out how far apart they are in memory, `(dp - ip)`. That is, of course, if doubles and ints sit in the same memory. They always do on the platforms I know, but is it guaranteed by the standard? Or is pointer arithmetic only allowed if my `char` pointers actually point at something with the same type?

Comment: Pointer arithmetic is only valid within the size of the object that the pointer points to.

Comment: The consequences of pointer arithmetic between `dp` and `ip` is undfefined, because they point to different objects.

Comment: The types are irrelevant, If you have pointers to two different `int` variables, you can't do pointer arithmetic between them.

Comment: @tadman You can't do any arithmetic with `void*`.

Comment: What does "addresses are in the same address space" mean? On a typical operating system there is only one "address space" for user-mode code. Remember `dp - ip` is just a random, utterly meaningless number on systems with [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization). The days where pointer addresses map to physical memory, like on 16-bit computers of yore, are long gone. Everything's virtual and fake.

Comment: @tadman  I was interested in what the standard says. I know that there is one address space on most architectures, but the standard doesn't guarantee must of the stuff that is also guaranteed there.

Comment: The standard doesn't really take a position on a lot of things related to memory management. There's just conventions like allocating things in the stack, the heap, or the data segment, etc.

Comment: @Barmar is the rule that you can only compare pointers that point to the same object? I couldn't find anything about it, but I am not that well versed in the standard. That is why I wondered if the rule that I can cast to char * meant that I should be able to compare the distance between two objects.

Comment: @tadman yes, but the standard does tell me that I can cast pointers to char * and that I can do arithmetic on two char pointers. That is why I wonder what guarantees I get about whether different objects lie at addresses I can compare.

Comment: There's no such thing as distance unless you're talking about a *single allocation* and then the distance is only relevant within that specific allocation. You'll get numbers if you recast, but those numbers aren't guaranteed to be anything meaningful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to factors like ASLR, and the lack of specificity in the C specification regarding how variables are actually positioned in memory, you really can't trust the difference of two pointers to two different objects to represent anything.

Are things allocated on the stack in a top-down manner? Usually, sure, it's a long-standing convention, but it is not *required* to be that way. They could be heap allocated, or strewn about randomly. That's unlikely, but *allowed*.

In any protected mode operating system you are not seeing real memory addresses, they're user-space addresses that might look and feel very real, but they're remapped by the CPU to their actual location in memory, or perhaps not even, as that memory could have been swapped out to disk, compressed, or other more mysterious and confusing things that are all hidden away by the kernel and CPU.

While you can take the difference of two locations within a given allocation, as in through `malloc` or `calloc`, the difference between two arbitrary allocations or objects is really not meaningful. Not only does the kernel add an abstraction layer, it will deliberately scramble the allocations it gives you through [Address Space Layout Randomization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) as a measure to make your allocations more unpredictable.

Why? To make it harder to weaponize a [buffer overflow bug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow).

So if you're curious about the position of variables in memory, that's great, have a look, explore, but don't presume that the strategy used by your compiler, operating system, or CPU won't change in the future in some dramatic way.

On any modern 64-bit CPU and operating system there's a huge amount of address space to work with, like 18,446,744,073,709,551,616 possible bytes, and while large chunks of this are walled off and reserved, there's still a nearly inexhaustible amount of space left. That's also multiplied by the fact that each process has its own address space, so there's actually a lot more than that in theory to work with.

Fun fact: Before 64-bit CPUs took hold there were unusual 36-bit memory schemes where a 32-bit operating system and CPU could address more than 4GB of memory, but each individual process could only "see" 4GB since it uses 32-bit pointers.

Answer (score 4):

Pointer arithmetic is only defined when the pointers have the same type and they point within the same object. More specifically, the [standard](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.6) says:

> 3 For subtraction, one of the following shall hold:
>
> - both operands have arithmetic type;
> - both operands are pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of compatible complete object types; or
> - the left operand is a pointer to a complete object type and the right operand has integer type.

and:

> 9 When two pointers are subtracted, both shall point to elements of the same array object, or one past the last element of the array object; the result is the difference of the subscripts of the two array elements.

(For the purposes of interpreting the above, a single object is treated as an array with one element.)

Casting the pointer types to `char *` addresses the constraint in clause 3, but a pointer to `d` is not pointing to an element of `i`. So you can't subtract them.

Answer (score 1):

Memory allocated for `malloc` may be used for any object with a fundamental alignment requirement, which includes all the “built in” types (*e.g.*, including special types a compiler might provide as an extension), per C 2018 7.22.3 1, and therefore all such objects must share the address space used by `malloc`.

Further, any types of objects can be put into a structure or union together and therefore must share an address space.